# upload_max_filesize doesn't change within Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I'm working on multiple file upload while that time I've got an error

> The file `"theOne.mp3"` exceeds your `upload_max_filesize ini` directive `(limit is 2048 KiB)`.

So after that I've increased the `post_max_size = 20M` and `upload_max_filesize = 20M` and checked it within `test.php` file it shows

[image: Screenshot]

Even though it shows `2M` within my Laravel Project and throws the error. What could be the reason behind this.

Comment: Downvoters please post the reason for downvoting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So finally I've solved it by myself might be I got downvoted for this but I don't know this worked for me even after `apache2` restart that won't effect within my project but after that `I've restarted my entire system` and it all works fine for me. The reason might be because of the cache memory but I'm not sure about that

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was running php artisan server in order to run laravel the server. So the changes applied for **apache** were not applied to **php cli**.

Apache

[image]

PHP CLI

[image]

What I recommend to everyone that faces this problem is:

1. print phpinfo()
2. search line **Loaded Configuration File** and see which file you have to modify
3. modify it, save, and restart your server.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! This was also my problem and I didn't recognize it until I read your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try this it may work ...

Create a file named php5.ini and copy and paste the below code into it. Then save it. Then upload it. php_value won't work in an ini file. It probably doesn't work because you left php_value before each line.

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp/
```

Then save the file as php5.ini and upload it to the root of your  site.

Answer (score 1):

As you told you have changed the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your `php.ini`

**What are the suspected issues**

1. Make sure change in the correct `php.ini` file if you have multiple installation of apache
2. Make sure that you have **restarted** your apache server

**Note :**

If you have written laravel rules change it accordingly like this, but it should not be the major issue

```
public static $updaterules = array(
    'uploadedimage' => 'image|max:5000'            
    );
```

Comment: I've changed the value within `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and after restarting my apache2 I got that `20M` within my `test.php` file but its not working within my Laravel File

Comment: In some cases, `restart` might not work. Have you tried `stop` and `start` your `apache2` ?

Comment: Nope its not working its still showing `2M` I've updated the one within `cli` also instead its not taking

Comment: What is the size of your mp3 file and what is the limit you set in your php.ini file ?

Comment: `6.9mb` and allowed `64M`

Comment: Ok, the exception is thrown by php or laravel application ?

Comment: Its by Laravel application `The file "theOne.mp3" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 KiB).` Even I've manually posted the value to `128m` even though its throwing error `The file "theOne.mp3" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 131072 KiB).`

Comment: You wrote any rules for validation ?

Comment: Thanks for your support I've posted my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33958134/4860986)

Comment: @FokwaBest You can upvote the answer, if you think it work !

Answer (score 0):

Restart PHP artisan serve (if you are using it).

I did all of the recommendations to no avail only to realise that I never restarted my PHP artisan serve.